# Бесконечный цикл асинхронно

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

Имеется необходимость на всём протяжении работы программы в некотором классе `Watcher` получать сообщения из некоего динамического буфера (`Mailslot`, для которого сделана обертка и имеется метод `string Mailslot.GetMessage()`). Класс `Watcher` создается при старте приложения, имеющего GUI, и, собственно, служит для наблюдения за содержимым `Mailslot`.

Разумеется, вариант с таким подходом работает:

```
bool DoListen = true;
while (DoListen)
    {
         var msg = Watcher.Instance().MailSlotServer.GetNextMessage();
         if (msg != null)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Insert(0, msg);
            }
         Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

Но такой подход не видится мне правильным. По идее, цикл опроса буфера нужно вынести в отдельный поток, или использовать `BackgroundWorker`, но подумалось мне, что данный момент можно было бы оформить и при помощи `async/await`. Но это не особо получается пока:

В классе `Watcher` создаю метод:

```
    private async Task<string> GetMessage()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => { var s = mailSlotServer.GetNextMessage(); return s; });
    }
```

И там же реализую цикл:

```
    public async void StartListen(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            string s = await GetMessage();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
               (FormMain.ActiveForm as FormMain).listBox1.Items.Insert(0, s);
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
```

Теперь при старте приложения пытаюсь вызвать цикл прослушивания, для теста пока вызываю из обработчика события `Load`:

```
...
var ct = new CancellationToken();
Watcher.Instance().StartListen(ct);
...
```

VS вываливается с `ArgumentNullException` при попытке вставки строки в `listBox1`.

Полагаю, что на момент попытки вставки `s` переменная, полученная через `await GetMessage()` действительно пустая.

Вот и возникает вопрос, как правильнее реализовать такой механизм?

**UPDATE**

Всё заработало именно в указанном виде, а ошибка возникала из-за использования `ActiveForm`, который становится `null` как только форма перестает быть активной (спасибо [Pavel Mayorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178779/pavel-mayorov)!)

Если отказаться от использования `ActiveForm`, то всё работает. `listBox`(или другой GUI-контрол) можно передавать внутрь метода `StartListen` по ссылке, или не использовать тут GUI вовсе (что и было сделано автором вопроса).

Comment: На null проверку вы куда дели? В старом коде она у вас была.

Comment: Ну и задержку добавить надо, чтобы ЦП не жрало.

Comment: Дополнил код и текст вопроса.

Comment: Поставьте бряк да посмотрите какая из переменных - пустая.

Comment: Как ни странно, это список листа: (FormMain.ActiveForm as FormMain).listBox1.Items. Именно он кидает Exception - а вот почему - мне не очень ясно.

Comment: А форма к этому времени уже успела создаться?

Comment: Да. Перенес запуск метода `StartListen` в обработчик кнопки вообще.

Comment: StartListen вы запускаете в потоке UI или в фоновом?

Comment: В потоке UI, по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: Если не вызывать метод `StartListen`, а предварительно заполнить очередь `MailSlot` - то при старте листенера он забивает список на форме сообщениями из буфера, пока они там есть. Но если в буфер попадают еще новые сообщения, то вот тогда и вылетает Exception.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, дело в форме. Не сразу, но она становится `null` внутри метода `StartListen()` (фоновый поток). Не могу пока понять причины этого.

Comment: А, ну блин, вы же ActiveForm используете! Оно становится null как только форма перестает быть активной.

Comment: Передавайте в метод listBox1 как параметр.

Comment: А лучше - перенесите StartListen обратно в форму, не дело обновлять форму из левого класса.

Comment: Про `ActiveForm` не знал, спасибо! Век живи, век учись!
Насчет того, что не дело обновлять форму из левого класса - это само собой, сейчас так только для тестов было. Спасибо огромное, разобрался!